# Run Hangfire job on MachineName queue

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

I will use Hangfire in loadbalanced environment with single database.
I need a job to be run on each of the server instances.

I tried to create a job with `QueueAttribute`, to which I would assign `Environment.MachineName` value.

The issue is that I need to pass constant values in attributes, which `Environment.MachineName` isn't.

How to configure Hangfire to run a job on all server instances independetly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every server that hangfire creates it uses machine name as default name of the server itself.
But you can manipulate the name of queue when creating the server , for instance  :

```
 services.AddHangfireServer(a =>
 {
     a.WorkerCount = 10,
     a.Queues = new[] { "default", Environment.MachineName };
 });
```

This way every server would have unique queue for your needs. After that you can enqueue your job like this :

```
IBackgroundJobClient client = new BackgroundJobClient();
IState state = new EnqueuedState
{
    Queue = Environment.MachineName
};

client.Create(() => Console.WriteLine(), state);
```

NOTE:
I haven't tested this - this is basic idea.